# What is the difference between transactions in SQL databases and MongoDB?

Tags: sql, mongodb, transactions

I have read a lot of articles that states key benefit of sql databases is transaction mechanism.

But starting from 4.2, MongoDB supports ACID transactions in shards.

What is the difference between those transactions? Or does it mean that MongoDB supports transactions in the same way as sql dbs and now there is only one benefit for sql dbs - strict data structure?

Comment: I didn't find explanation there for my question